# Index of intersection of subgroups in group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H$ and $K$ be finite index subgroups of a group $G$ with index $h$ and $k$, respectively.

I know that $H\cap K$ is of finite index in $H$ and $K$.

Is the index of $H\cap K$ in $H$ bounded by $k$?

By symmetry the index of $H\cap K$ in $K$ would be bounded by $h$.

In standard notation: does the inequality

$$[H:H\cap K] \leq [G:H]$$ hold? Edit: I meant to write $[H:H\cap K] \leq [G:K]$.

There are many related MS questions, but I don't see how they answer this question.

Comment: The suggested inequality $[H:H\cap K]\le [G:\color{red}{H}]$ is certainly not justified.

Comment: Consider $G=\Bbb{Z}$, $H=2\Bbb{Z}$ and $K=6\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you for your comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map 
$$ \begin{align}H/(H\cap K)&\to G/K\\
g(H\cap K)&\mapsto gK\end{align}$$
is injective because $gK=hK$ with $g,h\in H$ implies $h^{-1}g\in K$ and hence also $\in H\cap K$.

Comment: Thank you! This answers my (corrected) question in the affirmative, as  I indeed meant to write $[G:K]$.